# Ruby checking rss feed every X minutes

Tags: ruby, rss, feedzirra

I have a simple app that fetches an RSS feed and downloads some data. How can I get my ruby app to check the RSS feed every X minutes? should I just wrap all the code in a loop with a sleep?

Answer (score 2):

If you like the old unix stuff, you should use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cron). A nice Ruby alternative is [clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) (which is way easier to configure).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) if you work with Linux or [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler) in case of Windows.

Comment: Also there's "whenever" gem, nice Ruby DSL for setting cron tasks: https://github.com/javan/whenever